# PHP - Create a array from others?

Tags: php

## Hello everyone !

Starting on PHP, I try unsuccessfully since this afternoon how to create from two array of different size, a third array grouping the elements "matching" between these two array.

I have two paintings ...

The first is of this type (Table 1):

```
KEY => COLOR

[0] => green
[1] => blue
[2] => red
[3] => orange
[4] => purple
```

The second is of this type (Table 2):

```
COLOR => CHARACTERISTIC

[red] => blood
[golden] => ingot
[orange] => juice
[brown] => wall
[green] => fir
[blue] => sea
[purple] => tunic
[white] => angel
[turquoise] => sea
[gris] => wall
[yellow] => sun
[black] => night
```

I would like to get a PHP script comparing these two array and which, when there is a "match" returns the value of the color in question.

This is the result I'm looking for (Table 3):

```
COLOR => CHARACTERISTIC

[green] => fir
[blue] => sea
[red] => blood
[orange] => juice
[purple] => tunic
```

I tried this:

```
$min = min(count($tab1main), count($tab2main));
$result = array_combine(array_slice($tab1main, 0, $min), array_slice($tab2main, 0, $min));

print_r($result);
```

The problem being that I have the wrong characteristic, in fact, I get the first characteristics of the second array while I would like the characteristics of the color in question.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Firstly, these aren't tables they are associative arrays.

Comment: Can you please add the code you have to the question?

Comment: Please do not dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: I don't understand the first array. How can you have all elements with the same key `0`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry typing error, it's modified :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_intersect_key`,`array_replace`,`array_flip` to get your desired result.

```
<?php

$array_1 = array('green','blue','red','orange','purple');
$array_2 = array('red' => 'blood','golden' => 'ingot','orange' => 'juice','brown' => 'wall','green' => 'fir','blue' => 'sea','purple' => 'tunic','white' => 'angel','turquoise' => 'sea','gris' => 'wall','yellow' => 'sun','black' => 'night');

$array_3 = array_intersect_key(array_replace(array_flip($array_1),$array_2),array_flip($array_1));

var_dump($array_3);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however, how to keep the same order as array 1 in the results?

Comment: @Marie Are you trying to combine the two arrays, so that the index of array 2 matches the value of array 1??? why don't you just use a database for this task, it would be so much simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much @cmorrissey !  This is exactly what I was looking for ! :) (y)

Answer (score -1):

you can try multi dimensional array

```
$[0]['green']="fir";
```

Comment: What does `$[0]` mean? You're missing a variable name there.

Comment: How does this build the result from the original arrays?